Does anyone know how to fix this error code? TF2 face flexing

I'm attempting to face flex a mesh for TF2 using a TF2 face flex addon. but when I try to flex it, it gives me this error code. It seems very easy to get ride of but I don't know how to do it. Can someone show me what to type? Thank you!
blender_tf_flex.py
bpy.ops.object.surfacedeform_bind({'object': shape_obj}, modifier=sdef)

C_exec, C_undo = _BPyOpsSubModOp._parse_args(args)

raise ValueError("1-2 args execution context is supported")


Sorry, we are no developers here and not affiliated with the Blender Foundation, we cannot help with bugs etc., only with using Blender. And when this is a third-party addon it is off-topic here as well, please contact the addon developers for support. But just in general: you are using Blender 4.2, there have been a lot of changes in this version. Is this an up-to-date addon, is it compatible with 4.2?

The new context override method is bpy.context.temp_override not passing as a first argument.
Here is a cross version method.
import typing
import bpy


def call_with_override(override: typing.Dict[str, typing.Any], func: typing.Callable, *args, **kwargs):

    if bpy.app.version > (3, 2, 0):
        with bpy.context.temp_override(**override):
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        result =  func(override, *args, **kwargs)

    if 'CANCELLED' in result:
        raise Exception(f"CANCELLED:\noverride: {override}\nfunc: {repr(func)}\nargs: {args}\nkwargs: {kwargs}")

    return result


call_with_override({'object': shape_obj}, bpy.ops.object.surfacedeform_bind, modifier=sdef)

